# Where is the documentation for Facebook Connect for Mobile Web?

Tags: facebook, mobile-website

Has anyone seen it? Facebook made big announcements in 2009/2010 about 'Facebook Connect for Mobile Web' but now all I can find are broken links to pages that no longer exist on the official Facebook blog and in the developer forums.

Examples:
This blog post links to a page that redirects to the basic website documentation, not mobile web:
http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/299

And here is where the mobile web preview is supposed to be:
developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/mobile/preview

The main reason I am searching for this seemingly non-existent documentation is to find out if there is a clean(ish) way of adding 'Share on Facebook' and 'Facebook Like' to a mobile web application that does not bring in the entire fb.js library or rely on fugly iframes.

Did Facebook silently give up on mobile web integration, or did they just move all the documentation to a place that isn't indexed by any search engine?

Comment: Yet another dead link to the documentation that never was: http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Facebook%5FConnect%5Ffor%5FMobile%5FWeb

Comment: I don't think you can do all of what you need , it's a Facebook policy matter to dis-allow some frequently misused features like invites and likes. However once you use the facebook connect for mobile. You can obtain the access token and use the API natively, either by a wrapper or just a simple GET/POST http requests.

Answer (score 0):

It has a link on the home page:

```
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/mobile
```

Comment: That only covers native iOS and Android integration. It then offers this tiny piece about mobile web: "The mobile web is an important and growing focus area for Facebook Platform. Most of our desktop web technologies apply to the mobile web, making Facebook for Websites is the best place to get started."

Comment: 'Facebook for websites' is not appropriate for building functionality on mobile web. I don't want to bring in obscene amounts of cruft js for a simple 'like' button or use an iframe which won't work on Blackberry and some other devices.